# How can I link item by relevance?

Tags: algorithms

I am building a web application for used book trading and I am adding a feature to propose other book that would be interesting when they view an offer.

Currently the data that I store are the following (they are updated each time someone visit an offer) :

ISBN (book of the offer)
SessId (a unique id that everyone has when visiting the website)
NumberOfVisit (The number of time someone has view an offer of that book)

I also have access to some user update data which categorize the book by subject and course. It isn't necessarily up-to-date and precise, but it's nonetheless data.

What are the approach to list the most interesting books for a book ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many,many ways to do this....I'd suggest googling for some search terms to get started, such as "market basket analysis", or having  a look at Toby Segaran's "Programming Collective Intelligence" if you know python (even if you don't - it is pretty easy to understand).

Comment: "market basket analysis" seems like it's what I'm looking for, thanks for input.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at [recommender systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system).